# Borrar, modificar Strings

Tags: java

En clase nos han mandado crear un programa bingo, consta de 3 clases: 1)Main 2)Carton 3) Linea

La curiosidad del ejercicio esque no podemos usar Arrays. Tenemos que crear un carton de bingo el cual consta de filas y columnas. Generar numeros aleatorios que no se repitan lo he logrado, pero lo que no he logrado es ordenarlos, ya que nos han mandado que las lineas sean de tipo String y no se me ocurre ningun tipo de metodo o pasos ya que en internet y en los video tutoriales esta todo realizado con Arrays,
Os adjunto mi código. Muchas gracias de Antemano
Guillermo!

```
package bingo;
```

Clase Carton:

```
public class Carton {

    private static final int MINNUMERO = 1;
    private static final int MAXNUMERO = 40;
    private static final int MINCOLUMNAS = 4;
    private static final int FILAS=3;

    private Linea fila1;
    private Linea fila2;
    private Linea fila3;


    public Carton(int columnas){
        assert columnas >=MINCOLUMNAS : "debede de ser de 4";
        fila1 = new Linea();
        fila2 = new Linea();
        fila3 = new Linea();

        crearFilas(columnas);

    }

    public int generarNumero(){ // que no se repitan
        while(true){
        int rand = (int) (Math.random()*((MAXNUMERO-MINNUMERO)+1));
        String strRand = Integer.toString(rand);
        if(!fila1.contains(strRand) && !fila2.contains(strRand) && !fila3.contains(strRand)){
            return rand;
        }

        }
    }

    private void crearFilas(int columnas){
    crearLinea(fila1, columnas);
    crearLinea(fila2, columnas);
    crearLinea(fila3, columnas);
    }

    public void setFila1(Linea linea){
        fila1=linea;
    }

    public void setFila2(Linea linea){
        fila2=linea;
    }

    public void setFila3(Linea linea){
        fila3=linea;
    }
   /* 
    private Linea generarNumeros(){
       Linea linea = new Linea();
        for(int i=1; i<=filas()*columnas(); i++){
                linea.agregarSinRep( generarNumero() );

        } return linea;
    }
    */
    private void crearLinea(Linea fila, int columnas){
        for(int i=1; i<=columnas;i++){
          fila.agregar(generarNumero());
        }
    }
    public int columnas(){
        return fila1.longitud();
    }

    public int filas(){
        return FILAS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return fila1 + "\n" + fila2 + "\n" + fila3;
    }
}
```

Clase linea :

```
package bingo;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Linea {

    private String numeros; //NO NULO

    public Linea(){
       numeros=""; 

    }

    private void setNumeros(String numeros){
        assert numeros != null : "Error";
        this.numeros=numeros;

    }

    private boolean estaVacia(){
        return numeros.isEmpty();
    }
        //devuelve el numero que hay en la linea

    public int longitud(){
        return new StringTokenizer(numeros, " ").countTokens();
    }

    public boolean contains(String s){
        return numeros.contains(s);
    }

    public void agregar(int numero){        
        if (estaVacia()){
            setNumeros(String.valueOf(numero + " "));
        } else numeros+=String.valueOf(numero + " ");

    }
    /*
    public void agregarSinRep(int numero){
        if(numero.indexOf(String.valueOf(numero))==-1);
    }
    */
    public String toString(){
        return numeros;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haria algo como esto
Esto permite ordenar dentro de cada fila con el metodo agregarYOrdenar
Si quieres un ordenamiento global crea una sola fila con 12 columnas por ejemplo y luego al final del todo la divides en 3 filas de 4 columnas. Esto lo he hecho en la clase Carton en el metodo toString.

He modificado tu clase Linea añadiendo agregarYOrdenar.
También el metodo toString() Carton, para hacer una ordenacion total.
La salida seria por ejemplo:

```
13 14 17 18
21 22 25 28
29 31 37 39
```

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Carton {

    private static final int MINNUMERO = 1;
    private static final int MAXNUMERO = 40;
    private static final int MINCOLUMNAS = 4;
    private static final int FILAS=3;

    private Linea fila1;
    private Linea fila2;
    private Linea fila3;

    private Linea filaTotal;

    private int columnas_;

    public Carton(int columnas){
        assert columnas >=MINCOLUMNAS : "debede de ser de 4";
        fila1 = new Linea();
        fila2 = new Linea();
        fila3 = new Linea();

        filaTotal = new Linea();

        crearFilas(columnas);

        columnas_ = columnas;
    }

    public int generarNumero(){ // que no se repitan
        while(true){
        int rand = (int) (Math.random()*((MAXNUMERO-MINNUMERO)+1));
        String strRand = Integer.toString(rand);
        if(!fila1.contains(strRand) && !fila2.contains(strRand) && !fila3.contains(strRand) && !filaTotal.contains(strRand)){
            return rand;
        }

        }
    }

    private void crearFilas(int columnas){
    crearLinea(fila1, columnas);
    crearLinea(fila2, columnas);
    crearLinea(fila3, columnas);
    crearLinea(filaTotal, columnas*FILAS);
    }

    public void setFila1(Linea linea){
        fila1=linea;
    }

    public void setFila2(Linea linea){
        fila2=linea;
    }

    public void setFila3(Linea linea){
        fila3=linea;
    }
   /* 
    private Linea generarNumeros(){
       Linea linea = new Linea();
        for(int i=1; i<=filas()*columnas(); i++){
                linea.agregarSinRep( generarNumero() );

        } return linea;
    }
    */
    private void crearLinea(Linea fila, int columnas){
        for(int i=1; i<=columnas;i++){
          fila.agregarYOrdenar(generarNumero());
        }
    }
    public int columnas(){
        return fila1.longitud();
    }

    public int filas(){
        return FILAS;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        //return fila1 + "\n" + fila2 + "\n" + fila3;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(filaTotal.toString(), " ");

        int count = 0;
        String result="";
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
          result+=tokenizer.nextElement() + " ";
          count++;
          if(count%columnas_==0)
          {
            result += "\n";
          }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Y la clase linea

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Linea {

    private String numeros; //NO NULO

    public Linea(){
       numeros=""; 

    }

    private void setNumeros(String numeros){
        assert numeros != null : "Error";
        this.numeros=numeros;

    }

    private boolean estaVacia(){
        return numeros.isEmpty();
    }
        //devuelve el numero que hay en la linea

    public int longitud(){
        return new StringTokenizer(numeros, " ").countTokens();
    }

    public boolean contains(String s){
        return numeros.contains(s);
    }

    public void agregar(int numero){        
        if (estaVacia()){
            setNumeros(String.valueOf(numero + " "));
        } else numeros+=String.valueOf(numero + " ");

    }

    public void agregarYOrdenar(int numero){    
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(numeros, " ");

        if (estaVacia()){
            setNumeros(String.valueOf(numero + " "));
        } else {

          String result = "";
          boolean numeroAdded = false;
          while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                  String token = "" + tokenizer.nextElement();
            if(Integer.valueOf(token)<numero)
            {
              result+=token + " ";
            }
            else
            {
              result+=(!numeroAdded ? numero + " " + token + " " : token + " ");

              numeroAdded |= true;
            }
          }

          if(!numeroAdded)
          {
            result += numero + " ";
          }

          setNumeros(result);
        }
    }

    /*
    public void agregarSinRep(int numero){
        if(numero.indexOf(String.valueOf(numero))==-1);
    }
    */
    public String toString(){
        return numeros;
    }


}
```

Comment: La respuesta queda un poco escueta ¿Podrías por favor añadir una explicación de por qué tu código responde la pregunta?

Comment: Perdona, me podrias indicar que has modificiado y porque, nado un pelin liado.

Comment: Donde esta el metodo agregar y ordenar??

Comment: Perdona se me habia olvidado pegar tu Linea. Ahi esta el metodo agregarYOrdenar

Comment: He mejorado tambien la explicacion que se me fue al hacer copy paste disculpar

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ha sido de mucha ayuda! Un saludo